# Multiple-selecting using Shift key in Project pane of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, project-pane

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.2, I just tried to use and the Shift key to multiple-select a set of shapefiles in a folder connection within the Project pane.  I thought I had done this before without a problem, but I am now thinking that I must have imagined that because if I left-click on one, and then hold the Shift key to left-click on another only the second one is highlighted.

I can use the Ctrl key to multiple-select, which is fine for a few items, but not when I may have many.

If the Shift key is expected to be able to multiple-select in the Project pane, is there a known cause for why I might not be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Midavalo's comment:

> Shift select works as expected for me. I just selected 15 shapefiles
>   from a local folder from the Project Pane and they all added fine.
>   Also works with FGDB and SDE feature classes. Running ArcGIS Pro 1.2

led me to performing another test in which I:

- created a New Project using the Map.aptx template
- added the same folder connection in the Project pane
- was able to use the Shift key to multiple-select the same shapefiles without a problem

The original project continues to be unable to multiple-select those shapefiles so I will assume that something has gone amiss with that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

I closed ArcGIS Pro and re-opened. The tool must have been stuck. This worked for me!